# chrome and IE do not load the google font

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, fonts

I am using a google font (Open Sans) on my website. Tested in all browsers on my local wamp server, and checked out great.

When I put my pages live, I noticed FF is loading the font just fine, but Chrome (v23) and IE8-9 are not, they are just displaying Arial. I looked in the Sources panel of the web developers tools in chrome, and the font is not even listed there at all.

What steps can I take to try and debug this, or does anyone have a clue what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to show us a demo of where it's not working. Google Fonts, generally speaking, works. So if we can't see any source code, it's pretty damn hard to debug.

Comment: ok, good point... but the site requires login (which I can't give out). I am not sure how to give a demo... suggestions? I can provide screenshots and some source code, if that would help

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the site uses https, and I was trying to load the font with http url. Not sure why FF loaded it, but IE gave me the secure content warning message.