# Google fonts are not loaded in Chrome (google server returns not found status)

Tags: css, google-chrome, networking, fonts

I've been using the same google fonts in development for a couple of months by now and today they just stopped to load in Chrome (works fine in FF).

I have the following line in my scss file:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&subset=cyrillic,latin);
```

and I have the following requests in Chrome Network tab that return 404

```
Request URL:http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSpX5f-9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY.woff2

Request URL:http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/RjgO7rYTmqiVp7vzi-Q5URJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2

Request URL:http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzJX5f-9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY.woff2
```

Also it's worth pointing out that the requests' paths are different for FF and Chrome

Any idea what might've caused google fonts stop to work? I update my ubuntu everytime it offers updates, is there a chance it has to do something with ubuntu update?

PS if I simply open [link](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans:400,600,700&subset=cyrillic,latin) that I use for the `@import`, it shows me font-faces for all the types there are for this font, instead of just the three I need, and again, it shows me only 3 in FF

Comment: Did you try calling the https version of your Google font URL https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans, if your page is calling https then it should not call http resource.

Comment: No, I don't use https yet so it's correct to use http, but https version doesn't work either anyway

Comment: Give this a shot looks like you may also have the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome

Comment: I've read that one, it's a difficult issue. The css that it renders when I visit the link in the end of the question has links for fonts that return 404 (you can find a link that contains "9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY" and try to visit it) so I wonder if it's something wrong with google fonts and has nothing to do with my setup

Comment: If its working for you in FF then there isnt any issue with Google fonts.

Comment: it has to do with the HTTP/S way you are pointing to google fonts, please read this issue and how it got solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730846/chrome-and-ie-do-not-load-the-google-font?rq=1

Comment: I tried both https and http, doesn't work either way, I ended up downloading the fonts and serving them from the server itself

Comment: We have the same issue with Open Sans font on our website. Clearly this is issue with Google Fonts, not the browser. Google fonts serves different version of css for each browser. Version for Chrome contains broken font links.

Comment: yeah, it appears so. You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Can you try with other font family instead of opensans and check if that works in chrome?

Comment: I am busy at the moment, maybe later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/14. Chrome users of Google Fonts for non-latin scripts for Open Sans were temporarily impacted.

Comment: Nice answer, because 'links rot' it always including a summary ('bad release of the fonts by google, since fixed') so you answer retains meaning even if the link fails.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3):

Font Source url > http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&subset=cyrillic,latin

This looks like an issue with Google fonts, as when I point to /* latin */ http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzOgdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2 it prompts me a file dialog to save.

Where as while pointing to /* cyrillic-ext */ http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mxJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2 throws an error.

So it looks like font type is missing on the google server.

Comment: Seems to be fixed at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Google generates wrong URL's for some 'fonts.gstatic.com' fonts at the moment. This is Chrome specific issue only. The kernel of problem is wrong 'v10' part of URLs generated by Google.

I have discovered the problem for "Open Sans" font only.

For example, http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:200,300,400,600,700&subset=cyrillic,latin at the moment gives wrong URL for:

/* latin-ext */ "Open Sans", 300 font (add http:// before, as I can't add more than 2 links now as novice):

fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTT0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2

At the same time if you'll try to download same font with changed URL ('v10' with 'v11' replaced) using Chrome - the font will be downloaded without any problems. Just try the font link above with 'v10' to 'v11' replaced:

http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v11/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTT0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2

Comment: I just downloaded the font without changing anything and it works, but I am not sure if it's a good decision for applications in production.